# How to remove decimal date from a text file?

Tags: files, text, date

I have a text file where date many times appear in two formats e.g. 01.01.10 or 01.01.2010

Is there any command that will remove all the dates from a text file?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed -E 's/[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2,4}//g' file
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly.